# How to arrange bulk of geometry (lines which forms one string) to horizontally to make proper string from lines?

Tags: c#, math, geometry, dxf

[image: string "hijack"]

I have attached image written "Hijack" word inside. I write this string("Hijack") with such a fancy font in DXF file and save it as line/polyline. I am using DXF parser which gives me array of small lines which form this string but not arranged. for example I get lines of "a" first then "H" then "j" and all. Means not in sequence like "H","i","j","a","c","k". I have formed a `List<List<Point>> LinesList` where each `List<points>` make one connected path of letter in terms of Geometry and so I have total count to 10 for this `List`. i just want to arrange this `List` of `List<Points>` to make string "Hijack". I can form bounding rectangle of each path of letter from `LinesList`. i just need to arrange this rectangles to make proper arranged `List` of letters. I just sorted list by Bounding rectangle's X position but issues are for sequence of "i and j" here, as bounding rectangle of "j" 's start position is lesser then that of "i". So i get string like "Hjiack" instead of "Hijack". Help will be appreciated. I get proper string if i use normal font like "Arial", as it will be properly sorted by "X" position of bounding rectangle of path. this issue is for fancy font.

Comment: maybe you should test the order in two ways: in addition to the left also test the right boundary. this will reveal the i-j issue. not sure if you can find a way to resolve this fully without a list of 'kerning pairs'. Those are common in typography to decide  how to place overlapping glyphs, like T-a or AV.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @TaW. Yes using right boundary will solve "i-j" issue. good suggestion. And Related to "Kerning pairs" i have another question that, "kerning pairs" are part of Font right? DXF file which is saved as text to line/polyline format so how can I identify letter from geometry? Means I just have `List` of `Points` for specific letter. I think it's difficult to identify letter from points like say this `List of Point` generate "i" or "j" or "H" or anything.

Comment: _how can I identify letter from geometry?_ Hm, I don't know..

Comment: If these letters were created/typed into the dxf file in the normal way, for example; by typing H - i - j - a - c - k, it is possible the the Handles of the polyline entities may be also in that order.  That's worth checking anyway.  If that is the case, you could then sort by the Handle of the polyline entity to get the proper letter order.

Comment: @Stewbob : Thanks for a suggestion but I think typing order depends on user who is making DXF file. We can not assume if user will always type in order like H - i - j - a - c - k..